# Implementing swap test on quantum register

Tags: qiskit, quantum-operation, pennylane

I'm interested in implementing a controlled-swap operation on quantum registers. However, it appears that Qiskit's documentation primarily focuses on single qubits rather than registers. Could you provide guidance on how to implement controlled-swap operations specifically on quantum registers?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the two registers $q_1$ and $q_2$ have the same number of qubits then you can apply a controlled swap on the $i$-th qubits of $q_1$ and $q_2$ for each $i=1,2,\dots,n$ where $n$ is the number of qubits in each register. The Qiskit code would look something like this:

```
for i in range(n):
    qc.cswap(control, qr1[i], qr2[I])
```

while the circuit looks like this (for $n=3$):

[image: circ]